# How to group data in table in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table of data and I want to group by 2 columns. The issue I have is that for one of the columns, when I group them, I want to create a list of the elements in one of the columns but not the other. I am using dplyr.

This is an example of what I have

```
| col1 | col2 |
|  x   |   1  |
|  x   |   2  |
|  x   |   3  |
|  y   |   4  |
|  y   |   5  |
|  z   |   6  |
```

and I want to group to this:

```
| col1 | col2   | 
|  x   | 1, 2, 3|
|  y   |  4, 5  |
|  z   |   6    |
```

I have already tried grouping by both columns but that creates a tibble within the second column and I want to format it into a list.

Comment: We can use `aggregate(col2 ~ col1, df1, toString)`

Comment: @akrun You should add this as an answer.

Comment: @akrun I got an error saying object is not a matrix

Comment: @Mus the table is a dataframe not a matrix. Sorry stack is new to me

Comment: @akrun, you could also use `c` instead of `toString` depending on the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data name is `df`

```
library (dplyr) 
df  %>%  group_by(col1)  %>%  summarise(col2  = toString(col2))
```